# How to use an Angular 2 Github checkout in my project?

Tags: npm, angular

If I add [Angular 2 repository](https://github.com/angular/angular/) as a dependency in my project:

```
npm install https://github.com/angular/angular.git
```

then I cannot resolve my imports. For instance:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
```

will return:

```
Cannot find module '@angular/core'
```

Is there any clean and handy way to use a Github checkout of Angular 2 in my project?

Comment: Do you want to create an angular2 project, or you want to work on the angular2 repository? I'm not sure what you are trying to reach by doing this

Comment: `npm install` is supposed to install a package which contains ```a) a folder containing a program described by a package.json file
b) a gzipped tarball containing (a)
c) a url that resolves to (b)
d) a <name>@<version> that is published on the registry (see npm-registry) with (c)
e) a <name>@<tag> (see npm-dist-tag) that points to (d)
f) a <name> that has a "latest" tag satisfying (e)
g) a <git remote url> that resolves to (a)```. The github url only contains `g)`, hence, the `import` command can't find any module.

Comment: @BingLu Yes, I fully agree, that's why I ask how it should be done.

Comment: @DylanMeeus I want to create an angular2 project where I use a git checkout of angular instead of the current 2.0.0-rc.1 from npm.